# program IF-THEN-ELSE alignment

Tags: conditionals, program

I am using the 'program' package to describe a function. When I use the IF-THEN-ELSE statement I expect the lines to be aligned relative to the 'if'. But the lines are aligned relative to the 'then'. This is a simple example:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{program}

\begin{document}
\begin{program}
\IF A = B \THEN
    eaual
\ELSE
    not equal
\FI
\end{program}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How can I make it align relative to the 'if'?

One additional question: Is it possible to suppress the 'fi'?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I have edited the post as you asked

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can adjust the definitions so that

- `\THEN` does not run `\THENtrue`
- `\ELSE` behaves more like `\THEN`
- `\FI` unindents but prints no keyword

as follows

```
\usepackage{program}
\makeatletter
\def\THEN{\@marginspace\untab\keyword{then}\ \tab}
\def\ELSE{\@marginspace\untab\keyword{else}\ \tab}%
\def\FI{\@marginspace\untab}
\makeatother
```

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{program}
\makeatletter
\def\THEN{\@marginspace\untab\keyword{then}\ \tab}
\def\ELSE{\@marginspace\untab\keyword{else}\ \tab}%
\def\FI{\@marginspace\untab}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{program}
  \IF A = B
  \THEN
    equal
  \ELSE
    not equal
  \FI

  \IF C = D
  \THEN
    equal
  \ELSE
    not equal
  \FI
\end{program}

\end{document}
```

I started with the commands as defined in `program.sty` and mostly removed unwanted actions.
The pair `\makeatletter ... \makeatother` is needed as the name of the `marginspace` command contains the character `@`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and also for the nice explanation.